# How do I multiply the values in two array list, then add it to the second arraylist?

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the total cost of items in the users cart. My approach to this is to store the item cost as well as the quantity in an Arraylist, and then multiply the value then add it. For example this is my Arraylist. I would like to do 2.00* 5.00 + 3.00 * 6.00 + 4.00 * 7.00 + 5.00 * 8.00. What I have done so far multiplies the first number in the first array list by every item in the second array list this is not what I am trying to do, can someone help with this.

```
quaninityArrayList [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
priceArraListy[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]




ArrayList<Double>  priceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double>  quantitiyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        quantitiyArrayList.add(2.00);
        quantitiyArrayList.add(3.00);
        quantitiyArrayList.add(4.00);
        quantitiyArrayList.add(5.00);



        priceArrayList.add(5.00 );
        priceArrayList.add(6.00 );
        priceArrayList.add(7.00 );
        priceArrayList.add(8.00 );


        for(int i = 0; i<quantitiyArrayList.size(); i++){
          for(int j = 0; j< priceArrayList.size(); j++){
              System.out.println(quantitiyArrayList.get(i)*priceArrayList.get(j));

          }


        }
```

Comment: Try using only one index, `i` : ` for(int i = 0; i<quantitiyArrayList.size(); i++) System.out.println(quantitiyArrayList.get(i)*priceArrayList.get(i)); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, however, I would strongly recommend to use a single list where each element contains the information regarding price and quantity.

```java
float sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i<quantitiyArrayList.size(); i++){
  sum += quantitiyArrayList.get(i) * priceArrayList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses can you elaborate on what you mean by using a single list?

Comment: At the very least, since both lists are working as parallel Lists, make sure both are of the same size: `if  (quantitiyArrayList.size() != priceArrayList.size()) {`. problems